# Custom Content-Type validation filter?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-mvc-filters

I want to implement a custom Content-Type validation filter so that a custom error model on a 415 Unsupported Media Type can be provided.

Something like this:

```
public class ValidateContentTypeFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private const string JsonMimeType = "application/json";

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        string requestMethod = context.HttpContext.Request.Method.ToUpper();

        if (requestMethod == WebRequestMethods.Http.Post || requestMethod == WebRequestMethods.Http.Put)
        {
            if (request.ContentType != JsonMimeType)
            {
                // "Unsupported Media Type" HTTP result.
                context.Result = new HttpUnsupportedMediaTypeResult();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the MVC pipeline seems to be "catching" unsupported or invalid Content-Type values before executing any custom filters.  Even the 'application/xml' content type will be refused.

**Where would this be configured?**

My MVC configuration consists of not much more than this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include;
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new SquidJsonConverter());
        })
        .AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute));
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateContentTypeFilterAttribute));
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateAcceptFilterAttribute));
            options.Filters.Add(typeof(ValidateModelFilterAttribute));
        });
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Action filters are too late in the processing pipeline for what you are trying to achieve here.

The filter execution order for an "incoming" request is the following:

1. Authorization filters' `OnAuthorization..` method invocation
2. Resource filters' `OnResourceExecuting..` method invocation Model
3. Model binding happens (this is the place where the content type check is
   made)
4. Action filters' `OnActionExecuting..` method invocation
5. Action execution happens

You could instead create a resource filter. An example:

```
public class CustomResourceFilter : IResourceFilter
{
    private readonly string jsonMediaType = "application/json";

    public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.HttpContext.Request.Method == "PUT" || context.HttpContext.Request.Method == "POST")
        {
            if (!string.Equals(
                MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType).MediaType,
                jsonMediaType,
                StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                context.Result = new JsonResult(new { Error = "An error message here" }) { StatusCode = 415 };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you would like to modify all types of `UnsupportedMediaTypeResult` responses, then you could write a Result filter instead.

The filter pipeline for outgoing response is:

6. Action filters' `OnActionExecuted...` method invocation
7. Result filters' `OnResultExecuting..` method invocation
8. Result filters' `OnResultExecuted..` method invocation
9. Resource filters' `OnResourceExecuted..` method invocation

An example with a Result filter:

```
public class CustomResultFilter : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        var result = context.Result as UnsupportedMediaTypeResult;
        if (result != null)
        {
            context.Result = new JsonResult(new { Error = "An error message here" }) { StatusCode = 415 };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Result filters are new to me! This works perfectly - thanks.